# Restore Position Command of DraggableView C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xaml, xamarin

The problem is that when the touchevent ends the restore position command should be invoked and restore it back to the original position. I think the problem lies with my property changed event

The second problem is that it should be able to latch onto the closest number labels and sort of center itself onto them properly, however I've got no idea how to do this. I would just like some tips on how to do this, as I'm pretty clueless.

Grid

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="White" ColumnSpacing="10" RowSpacing="10">
            <Label Text="Red" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <BoxView Color="Black" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <BoxView Color="Gray" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"/>
            <Label Text="9" Font ="60" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="8" Font ="60" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="7" Font ="60" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="6" Font ="60" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="5" Font ="60" Grid.Row="5" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="4" Font ="60" Grid.Row="6" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="3" Font ="60" Grid.Row="7" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="2" Font ="60" Grid.Row="8" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="1" Font ="60" Grid.Row="9" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="0" Font ="60" Grid.Row="10" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black" />

            <local:DraggableView x:Name="dragView" DragMode="LongPress" DragDirection="All" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" >
                <local:DraggableView.Content>
                    <BoxView x:Name="image" BackgroundColor="Pink" />
                </local:DraggableView.Content>
            </local:DraggableView>
        </Grid>
```

Crossplatform Code, Xamarin

```
  public partial class DraggableView : ContentView
        {
            public event EventHandler DragStart = delegate { };
            public event EventHandler DragEnd = delegate { };

        public static readonly BindableProperty DragDirectionProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        propertyName: "DragDirection",
        returnType: typeof(DragDirectionType),
        declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
        defaultValue: DragDirectionType.All,
        defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DragDirectionType DragDirection
    {
        get { return (DragDirectionType)GetValue(DragDirectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragDirectionProperty, value); }
    }


    public static readonly BindableProperty DragModeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
       propertyName: "DragMode",
       returnType: typeof(DragMode),
       declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
       defaultValue: DragMode.LongPress,
       defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public DragMode DragMode
    {
        get { return (DragMode)GetValue(DragModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DragModeProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsDraggingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
      propertyName: "IsDragging",
      returnType: typeof(bool),
      declaringType: typeof(DraggableView),
      defaultValue: false,
      defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public bool IsDragging
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDraggingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDraggingProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty RestorePositionCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(RestorePositionCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(DraggableView), default(ICommand), BindingMode.TwoWay, null, OnRestorePositionCommandPropertyChanged);

    static void OnRestorePositionCommandPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var source = bindable as DraggableView;
        if (source == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        source.OnRestorePositionCommandChanged();
    }

    private void OnRestorePositionCommandChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("RestorePositionCommand");
    }

    public ICommand RestorePositionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(RestorePositionCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RestorePositionCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public void DragStarted()
    {
        DragStart(this, default(EventArgs));
        IsDragging = true;
    }

    public void DragEnded()
    {
        IsDragging = false;
        DragEnd(this, default(EventArgs));
    }
```

Android Part of the code

```
public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.View>
    {
        float originalX;
        float originalY;
        float dX;
        float dY;
        bool firstTime = true;
        bool touchedDown = false;
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            LongClick -= HandleLongClick;
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            LongClick += HandleLongClick;
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            dragView.RestorePositionCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (!firstTime)
                {
                    SetX(originalX);
                    SetY(originalY);
                }

            });
        }
    }
    private void HandleLongClick(object sender, LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        if (firstTime)
        {
            originalX = GetX();
            originalY = GetY();
            firstTime = false;
        }
        dragView.DragStarted();
        touchedDown = true;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }
    protected override void OnVisibilityChanged(AView.View changedView, [GeneratedEnum] ViewStates visibility)
    {
        base.OnVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
        if (visibility == ViewStates.Visible)
        {



        }
    }

    // What happens when you toch
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        float x = e.RawX;
        float y = e.RawY;
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Down:
                if (dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
                {
                    if (!touchedDown)
                    {
                        if (firstTime)
                        {
                            originalX = GetX();
                            originalY = GetY();
                            firstTime = false;
                        }
                        dragView.DragStarted();
                    }
                    touchedDown = true;
                }
                dX = x - this.GetX();
                dY = y - this.GetY();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
                {
                    SetX(x - dX);
                }

                if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
                {
                    SetY(y - dY);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Up:
                touchedDown = false;
                dragView.DragEnded();
                break;
            case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                touchedDown = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public override bool OnInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {

        BringToFront();
        return true;
    }
}
```

iOS Part

```
public class DraggableViewRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<View>
{
    bool longPress = false;
    bool firstTime = true;
    double lastTimeStamp = 0f;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer panGesture;
    CGPoint lastLocation;
    CGPoint originalPosition;
    UIGestureRecognizer.Token panGestureToken;
    void DetectPan()
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        if (longPress || dragView.DragMode == DragMode.Touch)
        {
            if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began)
            {
                dragView.DragStarted();
                if (firstTime)
                {
                    originalPosition = Center;
                    firstTime = false;
                }
            }

            CGPoint translation = panGesture.TranslationInView(Superview);
            var currentCenterX = Center.X;
            var currentCenterY = Center.Y;
            if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Horizontal)
            {
                currentCenterX = lastLocation.X + translation.X;
            }

            if (dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.All || dragView.DragDirection == DragDirectionType.Vertical)
            {
                currentCenterY = lastLocation.Y + translation.Y;
            }

            Center = new CGPoint(currentCenterX, currentCenterY);

            if (panGesture.State == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended)
            {
                dragView.DragEnded();
                longPress = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            RemoveGestureRecognizer(panGesture);
            panGesture.RemoveTarget(panGestureToken);
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
            panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer();
            panGestureToken = panGesture.AddTarget(DetectPan);
            AddGestureRecognizer(panGesture);


            dragView.RestorePositionCommand = new Command(() =>
            {
                if (!firstTime)
                {

                    Center = originalPosition;
                }
            });

        }

    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dragView = Element as DraggableView;
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);
        lastTimeStamp = evt.Timestamp;
        Superview.BringSubviewToFront(this);
        lastLocation = Center;
    }
    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        if (evt.Timestamp - lastTimeStamp >= 0.5)
        {
            longPress = true;
        }
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that when the touchevent ends the restore position command should be invoked and restore it back to the original position. I think the problem lies with my property changed event

1. If you want a `DraggableView`, then you should try to use `ViewRenderer` instead of `VisualElementRenderer<Xamarin.Forms.View>`.
2. `Renderer` is not a custom view, you shouldn't try to override `OnTouchEvent` in a renderer, it won't work, you can create a custom view in native project, then use `SetNativeControl`  inside your `ViewRenderer`:

   ```
   //Create this custom view in your Xamarin.Android project.
   public class DragViewNative:View
   {

      public DragViewNative(Context context) : base(context)
      {

      }

      public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
      {
          //implement your OnTouchEvent logic here
          ...
      }
    ...
   }

   public class DraggableViewRenderer : ViewRenderer
   {
       ...
       protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
       {
           base.OnElementChanged(e);
           //set native control to be your custom view
           SetNativeControl(new DragViewNative(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context));

           //other logic here
       }
   }
   ```

**Updates:**
For the issue of `RestorePositionCommand` not triggering:

The command is not triggered because you didn't call it manually. Since it's a custom `ICommand` that you have defined in your control, you need to call it manually to trigger it. For example the following codes will let it get executed in your `DragEnded` function:

```
//Inside DraggableView.cs
public void DragEnded()
{
    IsDragging = false;

    //add this line and your command will be triggered
    this.RestorePositionCommand.Execute(null);
    DragEnd(this, default(EventArgs));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how does this solve my problem with my onrestore command not implementing properly? Could you ELI5?

Comment: That's tips for creating a custom control in xamarin.forms, for command issue please refer to my updates.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the dragnative, am I just supposed to put the original Ontouchevent function inside the new dragview native?

Comment: I would like to say, that's the best practice, currently your codes still works.